# Xcode: won't add localization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

Usually adding a new language in a project is easy. I'm in the project tab, I press on "+" in the Localizations area, and then I choose the language that I need to add. It asks me which files I want to translate, I choose them, I press finish and then nothing. The new language won't appear. The project that I'm working on is full of frameworks and sub-projects. I didn't create it, so I don't know its full history.

[image: Here, for example, I just tried to add the Greek language]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I fixed it by manually creating an "el.lproj" folder (for adding Greek) and copying the Localizable.strings from another language. Then I moved it into my project and it magically appeared in the localizations tab. I think it's kinda of a bug.